# Why am I getting Application error while trying to load a model?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I've run this code

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass("Admin_Models_DbTable_News");
```

and my application has this folder structure

[image]

Why do I get this:

## An error occurred

### Application error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework ships with a concrete implementation of Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource that contains resource type mappings that cover the default recommended directory structure for Zend Framework MVC applications.

This loader, Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader, comes with the following mappings:

```
  forms/       => Form
  models/      => Model
      DbTable/ => Model_DbTable
      mappers/ => Model_Mapper
  plugins/     => Plugin
  services/    => Service
  views/
      helpers  => View_Helper
      filters  => View_Filter
```

Given your example, your class should be called **"Admin_Model_DbTable_News"**. Note that the "s" is left out. This class should be put in application/modules/admin/models/DbTable/News.php

Comment: Is this autoloader automatic or do I have to implement it in my application?

Comment: I've found out that it's happening because of my model. Check it out: [http://paste2.org/p/972127](http://paste2.org/p/972127). Is there something wrong?

Comment: Your class should be named Admin_Model_DbTable_News as it was before. The autoloader is not setup automatically, normally you would do this in your public/index.php file using: require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

Comment: At least, your model's name should be 'Admin_Model_DbTable_News' instead of 'Admin_Model_News'